RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Model:
I am getting
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Model:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict:

when I try to load my fine-tuned model that I tuned by the easyocr trainer.
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ar'],recog_network='arabic')


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to provide a full code to reproduce your error.
